# Hacknet Jailbreak mission

Tags: hacknet

I'm stuck in the Hacknet Jailbreak mission.

I already discovered the mobile, but I don't have the software to break the eOS device. 
It also says I need 3 ports cracked, but probe just shows 2 ports.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Save and restart the game to see if this nmap show the exact ports needed to be cracked.

Comment: Not a bug... just a case of bad mission description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I CAN'T BELIEVE!

For this mission, you need to reply the IP address of the eOS device!

The description of the mission totally throws you away from what you need to do!

Comment: I just tried this, it didnt work. what exactly did you do?

Comment: Well... people are saying that you need to login into the eOS device using ADMIN / ALPINE (lowercase) and then you can get the register id... the thing is that I replied the IP address from the eOS device (just to try and see if the game would accept it) and then I received the Job done email.

Answer (score 7):

You logged into one of the eos devices before. All eos devices seem to have the same username and passwords

Comment: Whoever minus-ed oned you is an idiot.  admin:alpine worked.

Answer (score 1):

You must hack a computer and run `eosDeviceScan.exe`, then there is an IP and you must do `connect *IP*`, then press enter-now you are in the smartphone. Then log in with the Username: `admin` & Password: `alpine` then your are done!